# Power BI - Direct Query. Comparing two tables in a delta table

Tags: powerbi, delta-lake, directquery

I want to create a view in which 3 tables or matrix are shown.

Table 1 and 2 have slicers which allow the user to select a "Forecast Cycle" on each.

I would like the 3rd table to show the delta's in values between the corresponding rows in table 1 and table 2.

The SQL View for both table 1 and 2 is the same.

So far i can do this in import mode, but not direct query.

Thanks.